# How to test MockKafkaTemplate when ListenableFuture is always null on .send(new ProducerRecord)

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to mock my response from `KafkaTemplate.send()` My main class is setup like this

```
  @Override
  public QueryServiceSendStatus sendMessage(
      String topic, Integer partition, String key, byte[] value, List<Header> recordHeaders) {

    try {
      ListenableFuture result =
          kafkaTemplate
              .send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, partition, key, value, recordHeaders));
```

Notice I don't have callbacks on my Listenable Future and have the class marked @Async, I have tried implementing this with callbacks as well and still run into the same issue. When running my full application and running a sort of smoke test the kafka code works as expected and writes the correct data onto its intended topic.

Here is my test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class QueryServiceProducerTest {
  @InjectMocks private QueryServiceProducer classUnderTest;
  @Mock KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template;
  QueryServiceRequest queryServiceRequest;
  QueryServiceSendStatus expectedStatus;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    int offset = 0;
    expectedStatus =
        QueryServiceSendStatus.builder()
            .offset(0L)
            .partition(0)
            .error(null)
            .partition(0)
            .topic("topic")
            .timestamp(123L)
            .build();
    queryServiceRequest =
        new QueryServiceRequest(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()), "data", "topic");

    RecordMetadata recordMetadata =
            new RecordMetadata(
                    new TopicPartition(queryServiceRequest.getTopic(), offset), 0L, 0L, 123L, 0L, 0, 0);

    SettableListenableFuture<SendResult<String, byte[]>> future = new SettableListenableFuture<>();
    future.set(new SendResult<>(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", 0, queryServiceRequest.getId(), "data".getBytes(), null), recordMetadata));

    given(template.send(any(ProducerRecord.class)))
        .willReturn(future); // Have Also used when().thenReturn
  }

  @Test
  void testQueryServiceProducerIsOK() {
    QueryServiceSendStatus status =
        classUnderTest.sendMessage(
            queryServiceRequest.getTopic(),
            0,
            queryServiceRequest.getId(),
            queryServiceRequest.getData().getBytes(),
            null);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedStatus, status);
  }
```

In my main class I want to do some stuff on the future to get the RecordMetadata to build my response to the class that called the producer (You can see I have am returning an object called QueryServiceSendStatus that I will be storing in a DB). The problem is during my test when I call `kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>());` result variable never gets populated even though I am mocking the kafkaTemplate.

I have tried mocking the SettableListenerFuture along with the SendResult that I use to create the SettableListenerFuture, but for some reason when `send()` is always called it is null.

Comment: Perhaps you imported the wrong `any()` method statically, are you using Hamcrest also?

Comment: I was using Mockito.any() @andy

Comment: Try mocking the interface instead - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475464/how-to-mock-result-from-kafkatemplate/57478836#57478836

Comment: @GaryRussell -- Sender no longer has the NoArgsConstructor making it hard to instantiate Sender, also since I am not using callbacks is that the best way to approach this?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean, I have no idea what `Sender` is; edit the question with much more detail.

Comment: @GaryRussell -- Referring to your link you gave me in above comment.

Comment: Post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so I can see what you are doing wrong.